# Loop through NSArray to collect specific objects

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsarray

I can't gather my thoughts at the moments and have problems figuring out a solution to the following:

I have an array of 5 `NSObjects`, Object-X. Each objects has two objects, Object-Y. Each of these two objects have a 50 objects, Object-Z, inside them.

Something like this.

```
Object-X 0:
    Object-Y 0:
        Object-Z: 0
        Object-Z: 1
        Object-Z: 2
        ...
    Object-Y 1:
        Object-Z: 0
        Object-Z: 1
        Object-Z: 2
        ...
Object-X 1:
    Object-Y 0:
        Object-Z: 0
        Object-Z: 1
        Object-Z: 2
        ...
    Object-Y 1:
        Object-Z: 0
        Object-Z: 1
        Object-Z: 2
        ...
Object-X 2:
    Object-Y 0:
        Object-Z: 0
        Object-Z: 1
        Object-Z: 2
        ...
    Object-Y 1:
        Object-Z: 0
        Object-Z: 1
        Object-Z: 2
        ...
 ...
```

Each of the fifty objects (Object-Z) has an CLLocation. I first run through all 500 objects and calculate the distance from the users current location and the objects.

What I would like to then do (preferably at the same time, if possible) is to take the closest Object-Z from each Object-Y in each Object-X and insert it into an array, so I end up with 10 objects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating distance, and *then* finding the 10 closest objects, maybe

1. dispatch, say, 5 blocks/threads (using GCD ... or a common multi-threaded approach), which would each
2. calculate 100 distances (for `Object-Y[0]` and `Object-Y[1]` of some `Object-X[i]`) while
3. keeping track of the objects with the min distance, for both `Object-Y[0]` and `Object-Y[1]`

When the blocks/threads finish, they can add the max objects to an array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear where the distance is stored, but if it's on the ObjectZs, then you could do something like `[objectXs valueForKeyPath:@"objectYs.objectZs.@min.distance"]`.